# Was the style of the up/down-vote arrows changed?

Tags: bug, user-interface, design, css

I noticed that the style of the up/down-votes button has changed (for me at least). At first, I thought it was a bug, but frequent reloading makes it look like a change.

Now, it looks quite similar to the ones here on meta

[image]

However, I can't find a post here or on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) informing about the change. What happened? Is this a bug?

Edit: A new answer on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398314/1264273) clarifies this.

Comment: There is also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows) on meta.SE.

Comment: Yes. It went from being a pretty terrible, unclear design to a moderately bad, extremely ugly, but clearer design. I have a still-semiworking userscript that reverts the arrows --- but as they change more things, parts are working worse and worse.

Comment: @davidlowryduda IMO the new one is better. At least they show up clearly. After some time I won't be able to remember how they looked when I first joined.

Comment: I should clarify: my userscript reverts the arrows (partially) to what they looked like in 2019. I find the circle-arrows now hideous.

Comment: @davidlowryduda where can I find your script?

Comment: I started with https://stackapps.com/questions/9443/revert-stack-exchanges-new-up-down-vote-buttons. There is a slightly updated version here: https://github.com/Tyler-H/SO-UserScripts/blob/master/OriginalVoteButtons.user.js. Others have some alternatives in the (unhappy) answers at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded. I also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389564/how-do-i-change-vote-arrow-buttons-back. At some point I fiddled with colors and forgot what the original was.